# How to not have a number included on the output of a countdown?

Tags: python

I need my output to look like this:

[image: Expected Result]

but currently, I'm getting this result:

[image: Current Result]

How can I fix the spacing to match the first picture, as well as make it to it doesn't print the "0" line? I just need it to say "you are all out of marbles" after the line of "you have 1 marble left" (like in the picture)

this is my current code:

```
marbles = 10 
marble_dots = "**********"


while (marbles > 0): 

    marbles -= 1 
    print("\n") 
    print(marble_dots[:marbles]) 
    print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.") 
    if (marbles <= 3 and marbles > 0): 
      print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!") 
print("You are all out of marbles") 
print("")
```

Comment: You seem to know how to use `if` statements so where's the problem?

Comment: Move the "you have x marbles left" `print` statement into the `if` block next to "Warning:". And ditch `print('\n')`?

Comment: while (marbles > 0): change it to 1 as while (marbles > 1): As zero is kind of null for us but not for computers

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `marbles` 1 lower, and move the decrement to the bottom of the loop.

```
marbles = 9
marble_dots = "**********"

while (marbles > 0): 
    print("\n") 
    print(marble_dots[:marbles]) 
    print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.") 
    if (marbles <= 3): 
        print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!") 
    marbles -= 1 

print("You are all out of marbles") 
print("")
```

Or use a range instead of `while` loop:

```
marble_dots = "**********"

for marbles in range(9, 0, -1):
    print("\n") 
    print(marble_dots[:marbles]) 
    print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.") 
    if marbles <= 3: 
        print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!") 

print("You are all out of marbles") 
print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would to be to add another condition to your "You have x marbles left." string, i.e. replace:

`print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.")`

with something like:

```py
print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left." if marbles != 0 else "You are all out of marbles.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Print and subtract at the end of each output, not the beginning.

Also, don't need a string slice; you can multiply strings to get a repeated character

```
marbles = 10

while marbles > 0: 
  print('*' * marbles) 
  print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.") 
  if marbles <= 3: 
    print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!") 
  print()
  marbles -= 1
print("You are all out of marbles")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of extra blank lines remove `print("\n")` in `while` loop. To remove last info about marbles amount you can end loop earlier by changing its condition to `marbles > 1`.

Whole script:

```
marbles = 10 
marble_dots = "**********"


while (marbles > 1): 

    marbles -= 1 
    print() 
    print(marble_dots[:marbles]) 
    print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.") 
    if (marbles <= 3 and marbles > 0): 
      print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!") 
print("") 
print("You are all out of marbles")
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help answer your question:

```
marbles = 10 
marble_dots = "**********"

while (marbles > 0): 
    marbles -= 1 
    print("\n") 
    if (marbles > 0):
      print(marble_dots[:marbles]) 
      print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.") 
      if marbles <= 3: 
        print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!") 
print("You are all out of marbles") 
print("")
```

Output:

```
*********
You have 9 marbles left.


********
You have 8 marbles left.


*******
You have 7 marbles left.


******
You have 6 marbles left.


*****
You have 5 marbles left.


****
You have 4 marbles left.


***
You have 3 marbles left.
Warning: You are running low on marbles!!


**
You have 2 marbles left.
Warning: You are running low on marbles!!


*
You have 1 marbles left.
Warning: You are running low on marbles!!


You are all out of marbles
```

We can move code inside of your if statement so that no matter what, a newline will be printed, but the other information will be printed only when `marbles > 0`. By doing this, our spacing is consistent and we do not print out `You have 0 marbles left.`

I hope this helped answer your question! Let me know if you need any further details or clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix the spacing to match the first picture

This problem is simple. Think about what you want your code to do:

1. Print the asterisks.
2. Print the count
3. If the "stock of marbles" is low, print that.
4. Leave some space and repeat.

So, one possible solution is to remove the `print("\n")` and add a blank print (`print("")`) after the `if` block, but outside it.

> make it to it doesn't print the "0" line?

For this one, you need to think about your while loop. One possible solution is to change the condition to `marbles > 1`. Think about the last few iterations. Once `marbles == 2`, the loop executes, and decrements that variable to 1. The value of 1 is output, and then the loop does not execute again.

An alternative solution is to make the decrement statement the last line of the  loop.

The former solution begins counting down at 9 and the latter begins at 10.

---

**Full code** for one of my suggested solutions.

```py
import numpy as np

marbles = 10
marble_dots = "**********"


while (marbles > 0):

    print(marble_dots[:marbles])
    print("You have " + str(marbles) + " marbles left.")
    if (marbles <= 3):
        print("Warning: You are running low on marbles!!")

    print("")
    marbles -= 1

print("You are all out of marbles")
```